# How to return different code and error with MockRestAdapter

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, retrofit, http-error

I use `MockRestAdapter` to return mock data in my tests, but I'd also like to test errors (401, 503, `UnknownHostException`, etc)
For `SocketTimeoutException`, there's an API, but how about different response code?

I've tried `MockWebServer` but no matter what I enqueue, I always get a 200 with the mock data from the adapter.

update: I want to run my tests like this:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginActivityTest {
  @Test public void goodCredentials() {
      activity.login("username", "password");
      assert(...); // Got back 200 and user object (from mock)
  }
  @Test public void wrongCredentials() {
      activity.login("username", "wrong_password");
      something.setResponse(401, "{error: wrong password}");
      assert(...);
  }
  @Test public void someError() {
      activity.login("username", "password");
      something.setResponse(503, "{error: server error}");
      assert(...);
  }
}
```

update 2:

Found something, rather ugly, but does what I need:

```
MockApi implements ServiceApi {
    public static Throwable throwable;
    @Override login(Callback<User> callback) {
        if (throwable != null) {
            sendError(callback)
        } else {
            callback.success(new User("{name:test}"));
        }
    }
    private void sendError(Callback callback) {
        callback.failure(RetrofitError.unexpectedError("", throwable));
    }
}

public class LoginActivityTest {
    @Test public void someError() {
        MockApi.throwable = new InterruptedIOException()
        activity.login("username", "password");
        // Assert having a time out message
   }
   @Test public void someError() {
       MockApi.throwable = new UnknownHostException()
       activity.login("username", "password");
       // Assert having a no internet message
   }
}
```

Still working on it, so any feedback will help :)

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly easy to do. You just need to implement `Client` and pass it when you build your mock `RestAdapter`.

Creating client with appropriate response:

```
Client client = new Client() {
    @Override public Response execute(Request request) throws IOException {
        final String reason = "Some reason.";
        final List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<>();
        final TypedString body = new TypedString("");//could be json or what ever you want
        final int status = 401;
        return new Response(request.getUrl(), status, reason, headers, body);
    }
};
```

And passing it to your `RestAdapter.Builder`:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("https://api.com")
        .setClient(client)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .build();

restAdapter.create(API.class);
```

Comment: @tibo I've looked. So?

Comment: I'd rather not create a client for each type of error, and I want to use the response from the mock api, using the same mock adapter (if possible).